# How to save data of a small prog?

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, jpa

I am building a small java application that shall run locally on a system. The data I intend to input is little stuff like my daily expenses, a couple of contacts I have, and a couple of notes of things I want to remember.

To save the data for this matter I think installing a database like MySQL or Oracle would be an overkill. In my past projects I always used those databases.

How would I have to manage the data of a small program? Are there any ready to use solutions in the java world? Maybe with the possibility to use it together with JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into Apache Derby:

http://db.apache.org/derby/

or HyperSQL:

http://hsqldb.org/

They're both lightweight database engines that you can fire up on application start-up, ideal for smaller projects.  They also both have Hibernate dialects for JPA.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @StuPointerException! Ok, they both sound very interesting. Where would the data be stored? As for Linux, would they be stored in the home-dir?

Comment: The file location for DERBY is specified with the property: derby.system.home, while the file path for Hyper is part of the connection String (jdbc:hsqldb:file:).  Both are well documented.

Comment: or H2 http://www.h2database.com  like HSQLDB but faster

Comment: Well, thanks a lot to both of you!